# Saving json data in a URL to browser memory on page load

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a URL which contain some data in JSON format. I want to save this data in local browser memory on page load. Later I need to use this local copy as a source for my JQuery autocomplete. At the moment I'm pointing autocomplete source to this URL, so its calling that service very frequently.
Please help me to save the data in browser local memory and how to use it for jQuery autocomple.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store it locally more permanently take a look at [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

You should be able to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $.get('http://example.com', function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem('autocomplete', data.toString());
});
```

And then on any page you can use

```
var autocompleteData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('autocomplete')
$('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({source: autocompleteData});
```

But it may simply be good enough just to declare a page scope variable and use that. That way it calls once per page load and you don't need to expire it.

```
<script>

    var autocompleteSource;

    $(document).ready(function {

        $.get('http://example.com', function (data) {
            autocompleteSource = JSON.parse(data);
        });

        $('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({source: autocompleteSource});

    });
</script>
```

This assumes that you can parse the response into an array in the appropriate format.

Update based on comment:

I think you will still need to pass in the function as the source, as you are doing a contains search (`indexOf(..) != -1`).

Your autocompleteSource would contain **all** of the nested data: perhaps

```
$.get('http://example.com', function (data) {
    autocompleteSource = [];
    data.countries.map(function(itemCountry) { 
        itemCountry.cities.map(function(itemCity) { 
            itemCity.destinations.map(function(itemDestination {
                autocompleteSource.push(itemDestination);
});
```

and then you would declare the method just working off the local data set

```
$('#myautocomplete').autocomplete(source : function (request, response){
    var filtered = autocompleteSource.filter(function(item){
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) > -1
    });
    response(filtered);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont want to save it permanently. Is there any other method to save it temporary.

Comment: @Nidhin - I included an example of that below

Comment: This is my current source. Could you help to replace it with "autocompleteSource"
 source: function(request, response) { $.ajax({ url: "*service url*", success: function(data) { var search_data = []; data.countries.map(function(itemCountry) { itemCountry.cities.map(function(itemCity) { itemCity.destinations.map(function(itemDestination) { if ((itemDestination.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1) { itemDestination.label = itemDestination.name; search_data.push(itemDestination); } }); }) }) response(search_data); } }); }